# Multiple operating systems issue

Tags: dual-boot

[image]

(1) As you see above from a snapshot of gparted, I have windows and 2 linux operating systems/ubuntu/centos installed.

(2) I do not need windows any more on this machine. I don't mind either installing a 3rd linux flavor or getting rid of the windows partition and extending the space for either of the existing linux flavors.

(3) Info::
I believe UEFI stuff applies to this machine.
Right now, it boots through GNU Grub and selects the OS to boot.
The boot priority is set to legacy in Bios.

(4) When I boot into live usb and try to make changes to the partitions, it gives me a warning that boot partition table will get screwed up. What's a good way to go about this (getting rid of windows), without screwing up the existing linux flavors.

(5)All the above partitions are on the same physical drive, but I do not know if they are primary partitions or logical partitions. If that's relevant to the solution, how do I determine that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, I believe that the indentation level gives you the answer to your question #5: ``sda1``, `sda2` and `sda3` are primary, and `sda5`, `sda6` and `sda7` are logical.

Comment: You're probably getting that warning because of the Windows partition with the boot flag set. If you have GRUB installed in the MBR rather than in the partition with the boot flag, then you're not utilizing the boot flag "feature". Hence you should encounter no problems deleting those partitions. Before doing anything, I recommend having the procedure for reinstalling GRUB into the MBR, on hand.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I've upvoted your comment but you should really post that as a proper answer as it answers the main question. I'd also suggest incorporating G-Man's comment as that answers the ancillary question.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting that warning because of the Windows partition with the boot flag set. If you have GRUB installed in the MBR rather than in the partition with the boot flag, then you're not utilizing the boot flag "feature". Hence you should encounter no problems deleting those partitions. Before doing anything, I recommend having the procedure for reinstalling GRUB into the MBR, on hand.

As for distinguishing between primary, extended, and logical partitions, as G-Man stated the indentation level shown in the GUI is used to indicate this.

Comment: (1) I don't know for sure, where GRUB is installed. I was of the impression it was installed in the 1st linux flavor installation. How do I determine any of that?   (2) If it doesn't utilize the boot flag, can I remove the boot flag first, so that the new installation is not getting confused due to that setting indicated on that partition?

Comment: (3) What is sda4 considered as? primary or logical partition? sda4 seems to comprise sda5/sda6/sda7.

Comment: You can remove the boot flag IF GRUB stage 1 is installed in the MBR and not in the first sector of the partition sda1. If you're not sure where the first stage is installed, you can simply remove the boot flag and find out. But of course, have a live Linux system handy before you try. sda4 is an extended partition (as shown in the GUI). sda5, 6, and 7 are logical partitions.